# Typescript enums and external modules (browserify)

Tags: typescript, browserify

Until now I was using typescript internal modules and included 10s of script tags to bootstrap my app. I am currently in the process of converting the project to use external modules (using browserify) but I am stuck at how I should be converting enums.

I used to have something like:

```
mymodule.submodule {
     enum MyEnum {
        one,
        two,
        three
     }
}
```

and I would use it in other modules as:

```
var val:mymodule.submodule.MyEnum = mymodule.submodule.MyEnum.one;
```

and this compiled to js correctly. After converting the project to use external modules, I moved all my interfaces into *.d.ts files and thought of putting the enums in there as well, but of course this produced an error since there was no mapping between enum and number in js.
I then moved the enums to *.ts files so that they will be compiled. Problem is that if I write them as:

```
export enum MyEnum{
    one,
    two,
    three
}

export enum OtherEnum {
    four,
    five,
    six
}
```

which works for requiring the enums in my code as:

```
import Enums = require('./enums');
var val = Enums.MyEnum.one; //this works
var val1: mymodule.submodule.MyEnum = Enums.MyEnum.one; //ERROR: incompatible types
```

BUT is incompatible with the `mymodule.submodule.MyEnum` type.
So how can I have both a declaration for the enum type so I can declare variable types inside d.ts files, but also have the actual generated enum code depended upon (so that it will be loaded correctly) and used in .ts file?

Note: these enums are used across many modules, so including them in the same file they are used is not a solution.

**UPDATE** about interface declarations:
it probably was not clear why I kept the original enum declarations in d.ts files so I am adding an example.

in interfaces.d.ts I currently have:

```
declare module mymodule.submodule {
    enum MyEnum{
       one,
       two,
       three
    }

    interface ISomething{
       aValue: MyEnum;
       aFunction: (anArg: MyEnum) => void;
    }
}
```

as far as I know I cannot using import statements in .d.ts files so how can I use one enum declaration in all cases?

Answer (score 1):

The enums need to be in a TS file because enums are compiled to JavaScript. When using modules, enums need to be imported to be used (even when just being used to define the type of a variable).

Change the code to the following:

```
import Enums = require('./enums');
var val1: Enums.MyEnum = Enums.MyEnum.one; // no error
```

Also, the enums should not be in `mymodule.submodule` if they are defined in `enums.ts`. Remove them from the definition file.

**Regarding Update**

To get the enums to work with the interfaces, you can move the interfaces out of the declaration file (`interfaces.d.ts`) and export them from a typescript file (ex. `interfaces.ts`):

```
import Enums = require('./enums');

export interface ISomething {
   aValue: Enums.MyEnum;
   aFunction: (anArg: Enums.MyEnum) => void;
}
```

Then you can use the interfaces like so:

```
import Interfaces = require('./interfaces');
import Enums = require('./enums');

var example: Interfaces.ISomething = {
    aValue: Enums.MyEnum.one,
    aFunction: (example: Enums.MyEnum) => { console.log('example'); }
};
```

Comment: And how can I use these enums in interface declarations then? I will update my question to display this issue.

Comment: @mxa055 basically, move all your code out of your declaration files. I edited my answer to show an example.